# Javascript RegExp test fails

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem with this regex:

```
(\[|\])[0-9]+,([0-9]+(\[|\])|inf\])\s?.*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/J20U2wgbffp8qFk6)

When I try to do code:

```
var rangeRegex = new RegExp("(\[|\])[0-9]+,([0-9]+(\[|\])|inf\])\s?.*");
console.log(rangeRegex.test("]1,inf] Test Expression"));
```

I always get `false`. Why?

Comment: Any reason you're using the `RegExp` constructor and not a literal? I'm pretty sure you'll have to escape the backslashes if you use the constructor. Or if you used the literal form, it should work as-is

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use the `RegExp` construct, you need to double escape with your backslashes:

```
var rangeRegex = new RegExp("(\\[|\\])[0-9]+,([0-9]+(\\[|\\])|inf\\])\\s?.*");
```

Or use a literal one::

```
var rangeRegex = /(\[|\])[0-9]+,([0-9]+(\[|\])|inf\])\s?.*/;
```

Comment: Not that it's that important, but shouldn't it be "escape your backslashes", not "double escape"? If you were double escaping a backslash, there would be 3 backslashes. Maybe I'm wrong. It's weird because "escaping" means using a backslash...and in this case, **for** a backslash character

Comment: @Ian Oh oops. Missed a word. Fixed now :)

Comment: @Jerry Ahh I see I see, that sounds better than even what I was suggesting!

Comment: And just to be clear, this does not have to do with the `RegExp` function _per se_, but with the String literal being passed to it, which itself is using the ` \ ` character as its own escape.