# Cannot find errors of the regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am making a version filter which accepts user input as a key. This filter needs to have a check mechanism to disable illegal version input.
My legal version is something like `1.2.3.4`, so I make a regexp bellow,

```
RegExp('^(\d+\.)*(\d+)$').test('1.2.3.4')
```

My original plan was that `^(\d+\.)` means something like `123., 1.  (\d+)$` means a chunk full of digits.

But it always returned false, confusing me; I am not sure what to do to further correct it.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22508589/javascript-regexp-test-fails - use a regular expression literal to avoid having to double-escape backslashes

Comment: Thanks a lot; this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RegExp('^(\\d+\\.)*(\\d+)$').test('1.2.3.4')
```

is right. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use the following regex pattern:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)*$
```

This would match a standalone single number, e.g. `5`, or a number followed by a dot and another number, e.g. `1.5`, and so on.  The trick is to make the entire `.NUMBER` term optional.

```js
// positive cases
console.log(/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/.test('123'));
console.log(/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/.test('1.2.3.4'));

// negative cases
console.log(/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/.test('1.'));
console.log(/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/.test('Jon Skeet'));
```

Comment: It would be great to have multiple tests (2-3 at least) with expected output as comment. e.g. `console.log(/^\d+(\.\d+)*$/.test('1.2.3.4')); //false`